# How do you map values from one 2d array to another 2d array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary, 2d

```
# input
a = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
b = [[-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3], [-3, -3, -3]]
```

How can I change array b to a -1 everywhere there is a 1 in array a?

```
# desired output
b = [[-1, -3, -1], [-3, -3, -3], [-3, -1, -1]]
```

On a side note I am rather frustrated with the fact every time I post on here its like walking on egg-shells. I was marked down in one question for providing too much information, then here when I tried to keep it a minimal example I was marked down twice for too little. I am new, I do not come from a mathematics background. I am a former marine who suffers from severe ptsd and type 1 bi-polar and I get my relief from trying to learn code. I am getting pretty frustrated with some of the snarky attacks I get on here when asking questions. Yes I have read the posting instructions which is longer then a legal document but it is often hard for me to discern what is the correct context at which to ask these questions when I know little to nothing about what I am asking about. I guess this site is just a big haze fest for newbies until we get good enough to code. So be it, venting a bit, maybe a mod will come talk to me and set me strait on how I should vent this anger....

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow! Most of us are uncertain as to exactly what you mean by map here. Perhaps you could give us an example input and what you'd expect the output to look like... that would help make it clear.

Comment: Hello, So sorry I was not clear in my question, I am rather new to coding. What I meant was if I have one 2d array like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] and I have a second like [[x, x, x],[x, x, x],[x, x, x]] and I want to change the second array to [[1, x, x],[x, 5, x], [x, x, 9]] mapping values I select from array 1 to the same positions in array 2, overwriting the values array 2 had. Again sorry for a lack of clarity I am still learning. –

Comment: It would help immensely if you gave a complete example of inputs and outputs _without any exes_.  How are the locations of these  special values specified; are they always on the diagonal or is there some other array that specifies them?  What have you tried so far and why did it not work?

Comment: Thank you David, edited for justice, I hope this is a better explanation of what I am trying to grasp....

Answer (score 1):

Nested mapping should work:

```
array = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]
array2 = array.map do |a|
  a.map do |num|
    num + 1
  end
end
# array2 should be [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Comment: This maps all values of the inner arrays, and does not seem to fit the description "map specific values" in the question. The question is unclear.

Comment: The phrase "map specific values" is pretty vague; the only thing I got from the OP is that he wants to map (which might refer to Array#map) on a two-dimensional array, so my answer shows how to do that.

Comment: When questions are as vague as this one, I do not think it is helpful to offer answers based on heroic assumptions, as it reduces the OP's incentive to clarify (or withdraw) the question.  Moreover, I believe that if they are not prepared to clarify, when asked, they do not deserve assistance.

Comment: Hello, So sorry I was not clear in my question, I am rather new to coding. I see that Cary Swoveland likes to take the conceded aproach with help so I will just ignore that user. What I meant was if I have one 2d array like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] and I have a second like [[x, x, x],[x, x, x],[x, x, x]] and I want to change the second array to [[1, x, x],[x, 5, x], [x, x, 9]] mapping values I select from array 1 to the same positions in array 2, overwriting the values array 2 had. Again sorry for a lack of clarity I am still learning.

Comment: Also thank you david for trying to help I will attempt what you said when I get off work. Must be imposible if you are new to coding to do anything on this site with how excited users are to -1 your questions...